# Remove placeholder item from drop area when any item is dragged in it

Tags: javascript, angular

Below is the stack-blitz link in which a simple drag and drop functionality is implemented. What I require is when I drag an image from the first div and drop into the second div then placeholder text like "This is drop area".

You can drop your image here." must be removed and image should be placed only. How can I do it in angular? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Link:--
https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-reoybq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Where is such text you mentioned ```This is drop area. you can drop your image here.``` in stackblitz?? I couldn't find it out any..

Comment: sorry sir, I have given wrong link. here is correct link.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdawsg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Do you want like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpfkup

Comment: Yes Sir. That's it i want. Thanks, you have saved my lot of time.

Comment: Glad to help you Rahul..